# How best to set up MDT developement and production?

Tags: deployment, mdt-2010

What's your MDT 2010 test and prod setup? What do you consider best practice?

**Linked Deployment Shares**
Is it best to use linked deployment shares, and replicate from development to production when testing is complete? What about backing out, if something breaks?

**Multiple Share Names**
Or what about moving the production share name from one deployment share to another, as you add and test more OS versions, drivers, attributes, etc? This might make sense if you weren't able to update boot images as easily - the PXE boot image would always connect to the same sharename, which could be moved around on the server.

**Distributed File System DFS)**
Does anyone run MDT shares in DFS, or is there no support in the WinPE boot image for DFS shares?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use a development DP, staging DP and production DP. We do our engineering in the dev DP, and testing from our staging. Once we're ready to support the DP, we replicate from Staging to Production. We haven't really encountered any issues so far.

As for the DFS, not sure. I wanted to take a look into this but I suppose it would largely be determined if WinPE supports DFS namespaces or not.

Comment: I've started using 3 stages, with linked deployment shares to replicate. The main reason was that I would occaisionally rebuild the first raw development MDT share, in order to get a simpler platform to trouble-shoot driver issues on XP.